# What is jquery syntax for finding a spinner

Tags: jquery, find, spinner

I use the following syntax to find and zero text boxes:

```
x.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
```

This does not find and zero number spinners. Is there a syntax for using jquery find to locate a number spinner?

Thanks to all...

Comment: You need to post more code. `x` could refer to anything. Looks like this is a jQueryUI thing, not a jQuery thing.

Answer (score 2):

This jquery selector will find all number input fields and clear the value.

```
$("input[type='number']").val('');
```

Comment: this is a very low quality answer